# "Valga la jaculatoria"?

Tags: traducción

I was looking up the meaning of *holgazán*, and this passage was selected as an example of usage:

> Valga esta jaculatoria, como desagravio a un miembro del jurado del
> premio Garvey, que ayer me reprochaba haber llamado holgazán al Santo.

What is meant by the first clause, *Valga esta jaculatoria*...?

Comment: Not sure which bit you want help with. _valga_ is the present subjunctive of _valer_ = to be worth, and _jaculatoria_ is a type of prayer. Does that help or do you have some other issue here?

Comment: Let this be a short prayer [have the value of a short prayer], as amends [or as an apology] to a member of the Garvey Prize, who yesterday reproached me for having called the Saint a bum. [or vagabond].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This form implies a 'Que" as in: "Que le vaya bien".

[Que] valga esta jaculatoria como x etc. [the comma is wrong, in my opinion]

- Let this be a short prayer as x
- May this then be a short prayer as x

This subjunctive form has three standard translations into English:

- May x [be something or happen]
- Let x [be something or happen]
- Let's hope as in Ojalá le vaya bien. Let's hope everything turns out well. May everything turn out well.

The sentence with valer jaculatoria is difficult because of the valer.

- Que **valga la pena** decir todo esto.
- Let's hope saying all this is worth it.
- Que **valga dinero** lo que estás haciendo
- Let's hope what your doing is worth money.
- [Que] valga esta jaculatoria como
- Let this short prayer be [have the value of] x

I hope this gives you a better feel for the text.